# HTML5 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

I tried to create a video tag in ASP.NET 4 in MVS 2010 but it didn't work. Is HTML5 already applied to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010? or do i need to install some kind of a software to make it function? I am asking about a safe Microsoft add-on or any other valid way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d